# Get REST RequestDigest on new (First Release) Library View page

Tags: rest

There is hardly anything left in the new (First Release) Document Library View, No SP Object, NO JSOM
and no more DOM element with the FormDigest we need to do REST, so all code with:

```
document.getElementById('__REQUESTDIGEST').value
```

doesn't work

The first Xhr call the new SharePoint page makes is to get the ContextInfo,

Anyone know where to get that Digest value?

[image]

Comment: Digging a bit `r.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue` is in `spoapp....js`, now lets find what `r.d` is ;)

Comment: It seems to save and read to `DataValueKeys` (`o.DataValueKeys.ResponseText`), that is then JSON parsed to make an object having the values. but it is certainly not easy to see where this object is stored

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, but you should be able to get the token by doing a post to `/_api/contextinfo`, it returns amongst other things the `FormDigestValue` (I guess that's the endpoint MS are calling in your screenshot...)

Comment: Yes, I did the call myself.. but I hate extra work,I am really looking forward to may 4th. if this IS the new SharePoint then a lot of people will feel like they're one a one way mission to Mars (untill Musk gets there in 2018)

Comment: Truly. Hiding and obfuscating and making it impossible to do custom adaptions of SharePoint will send it to a quick dead..

Comment: CustomActions work; just spent the whole day building it into (a future) iCSR LinkManager. And you can hook into KnockOut in a CSR like way... But it is all ductaping AFTER the page has loaded. So I do hope they show something CSR next week

Comment: that spoapp.js file is wild... function ``__extend`` is re-defined 152 times.. I think some engineer got paid by lines of code..

Comment: LinkManager with ``usercustomaction`` editor is at [https://365csi.nl/linkmanager](https://365csi.nl/linkmanager)